# ajax POST not sending part of object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

So I have this code:

```
var ajaxUrl = 'a/7776/as';
var data = {
    'answer' : {  'user_input'    : []  },
    'form_build_id' : 'form-ffe6f10e9601470ed4cfe38257a959a6'
}
 $.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(json){
    }
  });
```

However when I inspected the POST source it appears that 'answer' is not being sent..

Here's the POST source in Firebug:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
form_build_id   form-ffe6f10e9601470ed4cfe38257a959a6
Source
form_build_id=form-ffe6f10e9601470ed4cfe38257a959a6
```

Why is this the case and how can I get it to also send the 'answer' part of the object into the AJAX post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice explanation from T.J. Crowder, clearly knowledgeable. Here's my take at a practical answer. I inspected my HTTP traffic and ran your above AJAX request. As expected, `answer` was not being sent. Also going along with adrenalin's answer above, if you search for "ajax not sending empty array" on google, you can see just by the number of related results that this is also an issue. What I would do is if `user_input` is an empty array, send `null` instead. I tried it myself to make sure and, again as expected, this time I observed the `answer` parameter being sent in the request, along with `user_input` which was sent as null with the code below.

```
var userInput = []; //not sure where this is coming from in reality, but this is just an example.

if (userInput.length == 0){  //in this example, this is obviously always true
    userInput = null;
}
var ajaxUrl = 'a/7776/as';

var data = {
    'answer' : {  'user_input'    : userInput  },
    'form_build_id' : 'form-ffe6f10e9601470ed4cfe38257a959a6'
}
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(json){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The default `POST` encoding is [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2), which consists of a flat series of `name=value` pairs.

Your structure cannot be mapped directly to a flat series of `name=value` pairs, because it's complex. You have a member which is an object, which has a property referring to an array.

If you want to send an arbitrarily-complex structure, you have to use a different encoding and ensure that the server understands that encoding. For instance, you *can* send JSON or XML to the server, but you have to tell it that's what you're doing by setting the `contentType` property on the `ajax` method (which sets the type of the data you're sending **to** the server). Then your server has to understand how to deserialize that JSON or XML.

Alterately, ensure that your structure can be mapped to a flat series of `name=value` pairs.

A half-way house is to send data as `multipart/form-data`, but where you send a single `name=value` pair and have the `value` part be a different encoding, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {json: JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(json){
    }
});
```

That sends a single `name=value` pair with the name `json`, where the value is a JSON-encoded string. Your server-side would retrieve the value of the `json` parameter in the normal way, and then use a JSON deserializer to recreate the object graph.

This half-way-house technique is sometimes handy in frameworks that make it difficult to use something other than standard request encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot post a zero length array. POST (or HTTP query) keys do not carry any type information and zero length array would effectively build into null in a POST body: message = [] will serialize into ''.

Comment: This DOES answer the original question so whoever downvoted is expected to enlighten of his motive.

Comment: +1 The original question is why is it not being sent, and this is the answer.  Now this does not necessarily solve the OP's problem, but that depends on factors that are not included in the question. With this knowledge, he or she could at least find a different solution. An explanation of the downvote would be great here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `traditional` to true if you want the payload contains an array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (json) {}
});
```

Comment: That just makes it send `"[object Object]"` as the value, hardly useful.