# jquery not posting contents of json map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

given this very simple ajax post using jquery

```
function addEntity(parent, entity, successCallback, errorCallback ) {

    console.log("add entity:", JSON.stringify(entity));

    $.ajax( '/service/v3/rest/' + parent.id, {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'application/json;',
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(entity),
        success: successCallback,
        error:errorCallback

    });
}
```

note the console log that is identical to that used in the data field:

```
console.log("add entity:", JSON.stringify(entity));
```

outputs exactly what i'd expect the post body to contain:

```
add entity: `{"name":"some name","execute":false,"listeners":{"foo":"bar"}}`
```

That's exactly correct for what i'm trying to do.

What is actually posted (seen through Charles Proxy) :

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "listeners": {}
}
```

Why would jquery remove the contents of my map?

Comment: It does not get removed by Javascript. Something else is in play here.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037212/ajax-post-not-sending-part-of-object

Comment: thanks - adding this fixed it to the ajax:  processData: false,

Comment: `dataType: 'application/json;',` should be `dataType: 'json' 
`

Comment: thanks - i was playing around with the dataType but it didn't seem to make a difference - the processData: false did the trick.  If someone wants to post an explanation to this as an answer i'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

this magically made my post contain the map :/

```
function addEntity(parent, entity, successCallback, errorCallback ) {

console.log("add entity:", JSON.stringify(entity));



 $.ajax( '/service/v3/rest/' + parent.id, {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(entity),
        success: successCallback,
        error:errorCallback

    });
}
```